# Setting up a Ruby on Rails app in Production with Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, solr, tomcat7

I have created a RoR app which uses Solr for its searching (through the Sunspot gem). In development everything is fine, the sunspot_solr gem provides an easy solr instance for development. However in production I have seen different configurations, and I'm confused as to the advantages / disadvantages of each:

**Solr + Tomcat:**
I have read guides such as [this one](http://minhajuddin.com/2011/11/10/how-to-setup-solr-and-sunspot-on-a-rails-production-server), which outline the setup. However I am now getting [this error](https://gist.github.com/3150027). The whole setup seems very fragile, but if this method is best I will persevere. Any help / advice with that error would be much appreciated?

**Re-using the Solr example jar** [This method](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/solr-ubuntu-revisited/) seems much easier, just starting the example jar in the background. Does this completely replace the need for Tomcat? Is it poor performance wise?

I have a tiny bit of experience with Java long ago, so this is all very new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a production environment I'd recommend to use Solr running on Tomcat. Better if you forget the examples at all, which are meant to get up to speed with Solr and show what you can do with it.

The error you get now is pretty clear:

```
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory@/var/lib/tomcat7/solr/data/index
```

That means Solr is not pointing to a lucene index. Depending on the configuration you're using you should check your solr home or data directory settings.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The error was caused by the dataDir value in solrconfig.xml being incorrect.